# Using images in GDoc PDF output

Tags: grails

I've just found the option to create a PDF from my GDoc (`grails doc -pdf` - are there more hidden options?) but now I wonder how to use images in the generated PDF.
A line in my GDoc like to following

```
!name_of_image.png!
```

will include this image from the `../img/`-folder in my HTML output, but it will not show up int the PDF. Even trying other image types (I tried .gif) will not solve this.

Any idea?

**Update:** I digged a little bit in the source code and I guess I've found the problem:

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-docs/src/main/groovy/grails/doc/PdfBuilder.groovy#L60

Line 60: if you are on a windows machine, the regexp might get the basePath wrong. have to verify this...

**Update 2:** http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8809

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8809 for a monkey patch which solves this bug